# Regex to match charset

Tags: regex

I've been trying to make a Regex to match the charset of mime multipart emails so as I can decode them correctly. However I've found that there are some differences in the format that I can't seem to work out a Regex for, as I'm no expert.
currently I'm using `(?<=charset=).*(?=;)` however the examples I've found by sending emails from different clients are:

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed
>
> charset=US-ASCII;
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1

So my Regex works on first two but not the last, however if I remove `(?=;)` then I will also match the `format=flowed` part, which I don't want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `.*`, you can use `[^;]*`. That is, match anything but the `;`.

So, the pattern becomes:

```
(?<=charset=)[^;]*
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: nice one, I should have thought of that

Answer (score 1):

Building on this I've found this catches a couple more circumstances:

```
(?<=charset=)(([^;,\r\n]))*
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Match on either `;` or the end of line (`$`).

Comment: If `.*` is greedy, this will overmatch if there are multiple `;` following `charset=`